# Does the use of @Configuration prevent auto-detection of @SpringBootConfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-boot-test, spring-autoconfiguration

I've searched for the real meaning of using @TestConfiguration compared to @Configuration and I saw a statement in an official comment on @TestConfiguration.

> ...Unlike regular @Configuration classes the use of @TestConfiguration does not prevent auto-detection of @SpringBootConfiguration.

The statement came to me with a meaning that the use of @Configuration prevents auto-detection of @SpringBootConfiguration but @TestConfiguration does not.

I'm confused by the word, "prevent". Does the use of @Configuration affect @SpringBootConfiguration?

Comment: how is it possible to prevent auto-detection of @SpringBootCOnfiguration but with @TestConfiguration?